# How to Create Ensemble in Coq

Tags: coq

How do I create a set of elements in Coq?

I have looked at the documentation for Ensembles but I don't see any way to construct one. For example, in Haskell I'd use the "Data.Set.fromList [1..10]" to create a set with 10 elements. What's the equivalent in Coq?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As explained [here](http://coq.inria.fr/stdlib/Coq.Sets.Ensembles.html), you can for example do something like

```
Require Import List Ensembles.

Fixpoint list_to_set {A:Type} (l : list A) {struct l}: Ensemble A :=
  match l with
    | nil => Empty_set A
    | hd :: tl => Add A (list_to_set tl) hd
  end.
```

Comment: Thanks, but where is that explained in the given link?

Comment: The link is just the documentation for the Ensemble library. Based on the `Empty_set` and the primitives like `Add` or `Union`, you should be able to build whatever builder you need. Maybe I should have written "as described here" instead of explained.